# match indexes and elements in a nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list

```
elements = [['A', 'B'],['B','C'],['D','E','F']]
```

and I have list of indexes

```
ordered elements = ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

index= [308,302,303,405,506,609]
```

we know the elements and the indexes are matching by order

I want to recreate nested list by the indexes meaning the output would look like this:

```
out = [[308,302],[302,303],[405,506,609]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapping dict:

```
dmap = dict(zip(ordered_elements, index))
out = [[dmap[key] for key in lst] for lst in elements]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
[[308, 302], [302, 303], [405, 506, 609]]

>>> dmap
{'A': 308, 'B': 302, 'C': 303, 'D': 405, 'E': 506, 'F': 609}
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly but what if we have elements = [['K']], [['A'],['B','C'],['D','E','F']]
, if the list contain only one element it returns an error, the indexes are index= [300,308,302,303,405,506,609] and the results should be [[300]], [[308, 302], [302, 303], [405, 506, 609]]

Answer (score 0):

- prepare mapping (letter to index)
- iterate over the elements and assign to output (using nested for/list comprehension)
  e.g.

```py
ordered_elements = ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

index= [308,302,303,405,506,609]

element_index_mapping = {letter:idx for e, letter in zip(ordered_elements, index)}

out = []
for letters in elements:
    indices_for_letters = []
    for letter in letters:
        indices_for_letters.append(element_index_mapping.get(letter))
    out.append(indices_for_letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this although there are no safety checks here:

```
elements = [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
ordered_elements = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
index = [308, 302, 303, 405, 506, 609]

out = [[index[ordered_elements.index(c)] for c in sl] for sl in elements]

print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
[[308, 302], [302, 303], [405, 506, 609]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this, but if you want it short, maybe you could try this:

```
result = [[index[ordered_elements.index(el_l1)] for el_l1 in el] for el in elements]
```